# Iptables - Open Port Only for one Server IP (allow connections from a specific range)

Tags: firewall, iptables

My server has multiple IPs,

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
```

and i have a service which **listens to a port e.g. 88**

Now i want,

when somebody from outside, wants to connect to the port, that he can **only connect**, to that port, if he connects to the ip **1.1.1.2:88** but if he tries to connect to **1.1.1.1:88 it should not react** and it should look like that it dont exists and drops all connections.

Ok, than i need for 1.1.1.2:88 that only allows a specific ip range outside connecters.

for example only `9.*.*.*` can connect to that port and ip.

I'm using Centos. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 9.0.0.0/8 -d 1.1.1.2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 88 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d 1.1.1.2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 88 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 1.1.1.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 88 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 2):

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 9.0.0.0/8 -d 1.1.1.2 -p tcp --dport 88 -j ACCEPT
```

will restrict the source address (ie, who's making the connection) to `9.0.0.0/8`, which is `9.*.*.*` in your notation; it will restrict the destination address (ie, where they're connecting to) to 1.1.1.2; and it will only permit these for connections to the destination TCP port 88.

This assumes that (a) you already have a ruleset that forbids connections which aren't permitted, and (b) you get the rule **in the right place in your ruleset**.  If you want more specific guidance than that, please amend your question with the output of `iptables -L -n -v --line-number`.

Comment: i marked the other answer, he was faster. but thank you for your answer :-)